# How to install man command for chef

Tags: man, chef

I want to see manual for `chef` with command `man knife-cookbook`.
But it looks like manuals are not installed by default install `gem install chef`.

I found the man page of `knife cookbook`.
http://manned.org/knife-cookbook/061616e2

How can I install these manual pages to my local environments?
Normally documents are automatically installed along with software itself. I never installed manual separately.

I'm using `OS X 10.9.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-w` switch to `man` to see where man pages are being loaded from on disk.

#### Example

```
$ man -w lsof
/usr/share/man/man8/lsof.8.gz
```

So you could locate man pages for software that's similar to this and add the man page you want locally on the system to this same directory.

I did also dig this up, titled: [Chef Gem Man Pages](https://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Gem+Man+Pages), which shows man pages being installed via gem instead for `chef`.

```
$ sudo gem install gem-man
Password:
Successfully installed gem-man-0.2.0
1 gem installed
Installing RDoc documentation for gem-man-0.2.0...
$ gem man chef
View which manual?
 1. chef-indexer(1)
 2. chef-server-webui(1)
 3. chef-server(1)
 4. chef-solr-indexer(1)
 5. chef-solr(1)
 6. chef-client(8)
 7. chef-solo(8)
 8. chef-solr-rebuild(8)
 9. knife(8)
 10. shef(8)
> 9
```

This looks like a better approach to me if I understand what you want.

Comment: Yes, I don't stick with normal `man`. I could use `gem man` in CentOS. In OS X `gem man chef` gives me only `No manual entry for chef` though, it's ok for me if I know where I can see the manual.